# “Invalid JSON primitive: undefiend” in Ajax processing

Tags: jquery, json

I using ajax to all a page with jquery (no parameter need to be pass over checkFilesProcess()) . Error message display

Code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pgLoadFile.aspx/checkFilesProcess",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d != "" && data.d != undefined) {
                if (data.d == "0") {
                    $("#showCheckFileFailMessage").show("slow");
                }
                else {
                    $("#showCheckFileSuccessMessage").show("slow");
                    $("#trLoadFile").show("slow");
                }
            }
            else $("#showCheckFileFailMessage").show("slow");
        },
        error: function (ts) {
            alert(ts.responseText)
            $("#showCheckFileFailMessage").show("slow");
        },
        timeout: 60000 
    });
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Where's your `data`? Looks like your backend is expecting some JSON in the POST request body but you aren't sending any

Comment: Also** you should name your resulting placeholder "data" something other than an ajax parameter. Results* is pretty common.

Comment: @FirebladeDan no idea what you're talking about. The variable names used in the callback functions are inconsequential

Comment: In regards to your edit ~ *"no parameter need to be pass over `checkFilesProcess()`"*, are you absolutely sure? Your server seems to be throwing an `ArgumentException` which means you aren't supplying the right data. What does your server-side `checkFilesProcess` method look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request doesn't have a data attribute. Add a payload for the data and if there is none just provide an empty value

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "pgLoadFile.aspx/checkFilesProcess",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(someData),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d != "" && data.d != undefined) {
            if (data.d == "0") {
                $("#showCheckFileFailMessage").show("slow");
            }
            else {
                $("#showCheckFileSuccessMessage").show("slow");
                $("#trLoadFile").show("slow");
            }
        }
        else $("#showCheckFileFailMessage").show("slow");
    },
    error: function (ts) {
        alert(ts.responseText)
        $("#showCheckFileFailMessage").show("slow");
    },
    timeout: 60000 
});
```